# Delete/Undeploy selected soa composite application deployed on SOA server

Tags: ant, enterprise, wlst, oracle-fusion-middleware, soa-suite

How to Undeploy selected SOA composite applications from the SOA_server.

I have 70 application deployed on soa_server, few of them are important for future reference. I need help if we can undeploy the selected soa composite application from soa_server.

I have found a command using WLST on [oracle site](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13813/custom_soa.htm#WLSTC1705), if anyone can help on undeploying selected soa composite application in one go from soa_server1.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The use case you describe is suited to the use of SOA-Infra Partitions. Using partitions you can undeploy, retire, shutdown and startup all composites deployed to a partition as a group. To create a partition, in the EM FMC, go to soa-infra, then select Manage Partitions from the drop-down menu. Deploy the desired composites to this partition and then you can control them all at once.
This is how to manage a logical group of composites in "one go." Without the partition solution, you will need to script-undeploy each composite separately. These [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/admin.1111/e10226/soacompapp_deploy.htm#SOAAG3562) provide specific instructions.

Comment: hi Joe, thanks for your reply, I appreciate it, but unfortunately, this issues doesn't have solution.